# Let E be an incomplete Euclidean space with the Hilbert space as its completion Prove that dual space is isomorphic

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

How to prove that:

Let E be an incomplete Euclidean space with the Hilbert space H as its completion. Prove that dual space $E^{*}$ and H are isomorphic.

Comment: Show every continuous linear functional on $E$ extends uniquely to a continuous linear functional on $H$ with the same norm.

Comment: @GEdgar I considered your hint but I am still lost on how to do it. Can you further elaborate?

Comment: Do you know how to extend a functional on E to a functional on H?